# Linux Mint - Just created launcher does not show on MATE desktop but is in ls listing

Tags: linux-mint, .desktop, caja

I created a launcher by right-clicking on my Desktop, filled in the fields and saved it. But it didn't appear on my Desktop. So I opened Caja and it did not show there either. So I opened a terminal and did `ll` and it is in the list. I counted all the files and indeed there was one more in the terminal list than there was in the Caja list.

So I did `mv xxx.desktop FolderA` in the terminal window and then opened `FolderA` with Caja and the file showed there. Then I dragged its icon from the Caja window to my Desktop and then it was really there in all views.

This has happened twice tonight.

Is this a bug? What am I missing?

Comment: This seems to happen now whenever I create a launcher on my desktop and I can 'mv' it back and forth as many times as I want between the Desktop and a folder by commands in a terminal, and it never shows up on the Desktop or Caja view of the Desktop, although it does show appearing and disappearing from a Caja view of the subfolder. HOWEVER... doing a F5 refresh in either makes it show up in both.

Comment: This is a more general issue. When creating, deleting or renaming a directory or file in the Desktop folder from a terminal command, the change does not show on the Desktop or Caja view until after F5 is hit. But such changes show up for other folders in Caja right away.