# Linux Mint desktop displays different files from ls command

Tags: files, linux-mint, desktop

**Background**

I'm running Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon. After a botched attempt at migrating my data to a NAS, I restored my data from an external USB.

**Problem Statement**

After restoring from backup, all my files seem to be back the way they were before I started migrating to NAS, *except that my desktop no longer shows the contents of ~/Desktop.* Instead, it shows links to all the other folders in my home (Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, etc). The same problem happens when I open my file manager and choose Desktop under My Computer on the left - it shows the other folders in my home as well.

I can see that the Desktop folder is present in my `~`.

```
scott@dell-mint-17 ~ $ ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   17 Dec 17 08:25 Desktop -> /mnt/data/Desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   19 Sep 23 21:17 Documents -> /mnt/data/Documents
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   19 Sep 23 21:17 Downloads -> /mnt/data/Downloads
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   17 Oct 11 13:07 Dropbox -> /mnt/data/Dropbox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   15 Sep 23 21:18 Music -> /mnt/data/Music
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   18 Sep 23 21:18 Pictures -> /mnt/data/Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 scott scott 4096 Sep 18 08:25 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 scott scott 4096 Sep 18 08:25 Templates
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   16 Sep 23 21:18 Videos -> /mnt/data/Videos
lrwxrwxrwx 1 scott scott   24 Oct 11 13:06 VirtualBox VMs -> /mnt/data/VirtualBox VMs
```

I can also see that `~/Desktop` contains only two files, which aren't displayed:

```
scott@dell-mint-17 /mnt/data/Desktop $ ls -la
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 scott scott 4096 Oct 11 09:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 scott scott 4096 Oct 11 13:47 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 scott scott  279 Sep 19  2013 Exact Audio Copy.desktop
-rw-rw-r--  1 scott scott  752 Sep 19  2013 Exact Audio Copy.lnk
-rw-rw-r--  1 scott scott   91 Dec 23  2013 rsync~
```

**Question**

My questions are: Why isn't my desktop showing things that are actually in my Desktop folder, and how do I fix this?

**Things I've already tried**

I've already tried resetting the Cinnamon desktop by deleting the file that stores the desktop settings (`/home/scott/.config/dconf/user`) and rebooting, per one user's suggestion for another problem on Linux Mint Forums: ["After crash not displaying desktop"](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=129229). I've also tried removing the symlink, creating it again, and hitting F5, but that didn't solve the problem, either.

I've searched other questions - [Linux Mint - Just created launcher does not show on MATE desktop but is in ls listing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171222/linux-mint-just-created-launcher-does-not-show-on-mate-desktop-but-is-in-ls-li) and [Why are my application.desktop files not showing up in Linux application menu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66555/why-are-my-application-desktop-files-not-showing-up-in-linux-application-menu) - neither of these addresses my specific issue (or if they do, then I wasn't able to connect the dots).

Comment: What does `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` contain, if this file exists? If you create a new file in your home directory, does it appear on your graphical desktop?

Comment: Aha! It had contained `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"`. After changing it to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"` and rebooting, my Desktop displays the files from `~/Desktop` now. Thank you so much! Do you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under [Freedesktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org)-compliant desktop environments, including Cinnamon, Gnome, KDE, Xfce, etc., the desktop shows the content of the directory `~/Desktop` by default. This location can be changed by editing the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` and changing the `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` setting. Other settings in this file include the downloads directory (`XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR`), the music directory (`XDG_MUSIC_DIR`), etc. If a setting is missing or the file doesn't exist, a default name in the home directory is used (`~/Desktop`, `~/Downloads`, `~/Music`, etc.). See the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg_user_directories) and the [Freedesktop documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/) for more information.

It appears that your desktop is showing the contents of your home directory, which in the shell can be represented by `"$HOME"` or by the character `~`. This presumably indicates that you have a file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` with the setting `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME"`. If that's the case, change it to `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"`. I think you have to log out and back in in order for this change to take effect.